# how do i connect my HADOOP sample application to an active website for reading live data

Tags: java, hadoop

i have created an application using HADOOP to retrieve certain information from a huge junk data.now i want to do the same for the data generated from a active website so please help me how to connect my app to read data from the website

Comment: This is a very vague question.  Are you asking for a web scraping library to use with Java? How do you want to implement this? Where is the data stored?

Comment: hey it is simple i want do analysis on big data so i created an app using HADOOP ,the functionality of the  app is when we give a huge junk data as an input , it will analyze the whole data and provide us with the required results the results may be any thing (a city name ,weather info of certain city ,traffic info of certain country etc ) now i want to do the same thing for the data generated from active website live

Comment: For streaming of data, you can use a combination of kakfka(reading data and sedning to kafka broker - a messaging system) and storm(to read the streaming data from kafka). On the other side of storm, you can store your data in hadoop/hbase. This is the first part(storing streaming data) of analysis part. For analysis part, you can use Map reduce/ hive to fetch the data stored above. The above is based on your question in general - handling streaming data.